# How to use PAYPAL buy now button in PHP website?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-processing

I have a question. I want to use paypal as payment gateway on my PHP website. I know how to use it. I mean I know how to implement it on my web but I don't know the last part of process. I mean when user click on pay now, user will be redirected to paypal site and can pay amount by paypal account or credit/debit card. But how will I know that transaction is successful or not? What data will I get from paypal to my website? I can create automatic system that detects payment was successful or not once I know what data will I receive from paypal site. So can anyone help me?

I've found this tuotorial on website her http://b89.in/mZluLD so please if anyone knows good or better or different way to use paypal service, let me know.

And one more thing, I am using mysqli instead of mysql connection.

Thank you.

Comment: Please one question at time. If you don't know how to use paypal - that's one question. If you don't know how to use mysqli - that's another.

Comment: I know how to use mysqli. I just wanted to tell you that if anyone knows a better way then tell me and I am using mysqli that what I clarified. ;) thats all. :D

Comment: mysqli has absolutely nothing to do with paypal.

Comment: I know, but if anyone suggest me any new script, that person can suggest me script with mysqli too. Thats all.

Comment: again, database backend has nothing to do with payment. it is up to you how to manage your database.

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial you linked is the correct way to do it...using [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

[Here's a template](http://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-instant-payment-notification-ipn-php-template/) that will get you up and running very quickly with IPN.  It comes complete with a MySQL table installer and it will log all of the IPN data in the database for you, as well as provide a very basic web-based admin panel.

If you're using PHP 5.3+ (and actually utilizing it) then you'll find better IPN class libraries available on GitHub and Packagist.